# If a table column corresponding to different target columns in different tables, how to join this column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

While I was reading [the documentation of sys.allocation_units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), I found the following description for its `container_id` column.

```
ID of the storage container associated with the allocation unit.

If type = 1 or 3 in a rowstore index container_id = sys.partitions.hobt_id.

If type = 1 or 3 in a columnstore index, container_id = sys.column_store_row_groups.delta_store_hobt_id.

If type is 2, then container_id = sys.partitions.partition_id.

0 = Allocation unit marked for deferred drop
```

So sometimes it refers to `sys.partitions.hobt_id`, other times it refers to `sys.partitions.partition_id`. The good news it that they are just different column on the same table, so I can use a `CASE` statement in the `ON` clause to join. But what if it refers to different columns of different table, how can I write the SQL to join it? I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you would likely use an outer join, like a `LEFT JOIN` to the multiple tables it may or may not join to, with the extra conditions in each `JOIN` clause for each case to safeguard against the chance the same value exists in multiple tables.

E.g:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
    ON T1.SomeField = T2.SomeField
    AND T1.Type = 1 -- Safeguard condition
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS T3
    ON T1.SomeField = T3.SomeOtherField
    AND T1.Type = 2 -- Safeguard condition
```

This would then keep all the rows from `Table1` and match the correct related rows from `Table2` and `Table3`.